# Use parameters as regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parameter-passing

I'm getting an regex expression as a parameter of my script. Simply like `/stat.*\.log/`.

I tried to use it with the builtin grep of Perl.

```
my @dots = readdir($dh);
@dots=grep($conf->{classifier_regx}, @dots);
```

where `@dots` is a full directory with files and sub folder. And $conf->{classifer_regx} is the regex giving in parameters.

Actually that returns me all the files and subfolders. Is it possible to grep on a value at runtime? How can I do that? Did I miss something? Man page?

Comment: `my $value = $conf->{classifier_regx}; grep(/$value/, @dots);`?

Comment: Okay this work. but why i can't do
`grep(/$conf->{classifier_regx}/, @dots);`

he was giving all subfolder and files.

Anyway Thanks !


__Edit__: Nevermind, i should did something wrong. the old line work also.

Comment: You're welcome. The original is lacking `//` in your first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're lacking `//` in your `grep`:

```
@dots = grep(/$conf->{classifier_regx}/, @dots);
```

If this still doesn't work, you can try with

```
my $value = $conf->{classifier_regx};
@dots = grep(/$value/, @dots);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a Bash script it is much easier, since you can use grep onside the script. However since you are using Perl you can do the following:

```
my @dots = readdir($dh);

$str = <STDIN>; //This will allow you to enter a string at runtime
chomp str;

foreach $i (@dots) { // Iterate through the array. If a value is found, print it
    if ($i eq $str) {
        print "$str";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, Perl has its won `grep`.